# Manually add video file to Chrome cache

Tags: google-chrome, video, browser-cache

This might be a bit of an odd question considering most people want to do the opposite (i.e, save a video file to disk from cache), but I'm using CyTube (http://cytu.be/) to simulwatch shows with my friends. Now my internet connection is pretty bad/unreliable and thus when I stream something it leads to an annoying amount of buffering.

Thus I was thinking whether it's possible to download the file that we're going to watch in advance and add it to Chrome's cache manually. CyTube loads and plays the file directly from the external source so if I already have it in my cache then would it play without a hitch? Is it even possible to add something to the cache manually? If so, how does one go about it?

Comment: Why not simply play the downloaded file in a player?

Comment: @Hennes, the point is to simulwatch the file with others using CyTube. While simulwatching can be achieved in the somewhat crude manner of everyone getting on Skype and hitting play at the same time, CyTube keeps the video in sync across all viewers. So if I see something happening, I can be certain that everyone else is also seeing the same thing simultaneously, not at a delay of +/- 5 seconds.